# Downloaded React template: Compiled with problems

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie in React.js and I downloaded sample template created in React but the package manager the creator used is Yarn and I'm having difficulty installing Yarn. So I stick to npm which is the one my guide is using.

However, upon running this downloaded template, I'm having errors as seen as below. I already deleted yarn.lock and the problem still persists.

[image]

Comment: Have you ran `npm install react-toastify react-icons`?

Comment: "*upon running this downloaded template*" if you meant you have `git pull`ed / `git clone`d something from GitHub then you'd need to run `npm install` to install all the dependencies listed in `package.json`.

Comment: [Please include errors as formatted text rather than images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/438992)

Comment: oh i get it. I thought it is because of yarn, Thanks @Aleksandar.